# UITableViewCells not appearing in iOS 7.1.2 on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a slew of problems that as far as I am aware only appear in iOS 7.1.2; though I am unsure whether it appears in earlier versions. On iOS 7, I believe it is fine, and on simulator.

EDIT **FURTHER SPECIFICATION **

On iOS 7.1.2 it works on a iPhone 5 but not a iPhone 5S

When I run on a device, not in simulator. The first cell appears, but subsequent cells do NOT appear. Logging in the dequeue method shows that the cell is instantiated and dequeued however. In addition, the first cell is totally unresponsive to UI except scrolling in the cell. When I drag the cell up toward the top, it appears until reaching the top of the table view and then disappears completely. When I drag the cell down, everything works normally.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
if(indexPath.row==0)
{
    [self.restaurant sortRewards];
    HeaderCell *headerCell = (HeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //set up the labels to be loaded from restaurant
    headerCell.restaurantName.text=self.restaurant.name;
    headerCell.restaurantType.text=self.restaurant.placeType;
    headerCell.restaurantDetails.text=[self.restaurant getFormattedDetails];
    headerCell.priceRating.text = [self.restaurant getPriceRatingString];
    headerCell.address.text=self.restaurant.address;
    headerCell.cityStateZip.text=[self.restaurant getCityStateZipString];
    headerCell.phoneNumber.text=[self.restaurant phoneNumber];
    headerCell.description.text=self.restaurant.restaurantDescription;
    //set up the top most image from the header property of the restaurant
    if([self.restaurant isHeaderLoaded]==YES)
    {
        headerCell.restaurantHeader.image=self.restaurant.header;
        NSLog(@"Apparently the image loaded");
    }else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ // 1
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self.restaurant headerURL]];
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                self.restaurant.header=img;
                self.restaurant.isHeaderLoaded=YES;
                headerCell.restaurantHeader.image=img;
            });
        });
    }
    //load the correct badge for wireless or not
    //as well as the correct use woblet now button
    UIImage* image;
    if(self.restaurant.isSitDown)
    {
       image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_wireless-1"];
        [headerCell.useWobletNow setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Use Woblet Button Wireless"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [headerCell.useWobletNow setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Use Woblet Button QR"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_qr_code-1"];
    }
    headerCell.isSitdownBadge.image=image;
    //set up the map
    [headerCell.map setCenterCoordinate:[self.restaurant.location coordinate] animated:YES];
    //set a pin on the map
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:[self.restaurant.location coordinate]];
    [headerCell.map addAnnotation:annotation];
    //zoom that motherfucker in
    [self zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:headerCell.map animated:NO];
    //set up the points circle
    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, headerCell.pointsImage.frame.size.height, headerCell.pointsImage.frame.size.height);
    int percent = [self.restaurant.numberOfPoints intValue]%[[(Reward *)[self.restaurant.rewards objectAtIndex:[self.restaurant.rewards count]-1] pointsRequired] intValue];
    percent = 100*percent/[[(Reward *)[self.restaurant.rewards objectAtIndex:[self.restaurant.rewards count]-1] pointsRequired] intValue];
    [view applyCircleWithPercentage:percent andText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.restaurant.numberOfPoints stringValue]] andTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0f/255.0f green:98.0f/255.0f blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    //set the blue swirl
    [headerCell.pointsImage addSubview:view];
    //set the number of points until the next reward

    headerCell.pointsUntilNextReward.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d pts",[self.restaurant pointsUntilNextReward]];
    //assign our return cell to header cell

    return headerCell;

}
else
{
    //instantiate a RewardCell to reassign to cell at a later point
    RewardCell *rewardCell;
    //pull the appropriate reward from the restaurant
    Reward *reward = [[self.restaurant rewards] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
    if([reward.pointsRequired intValue]<=[self.restaurant.numberOfPoints intValue])
    {
        //if you have more points that the points required for a given reward dequeue with the identifier reward cell on in order to use the appropriate UI.
        rewardCell = (RewardCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RewardCellOn" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise you need to use the UI for when you don't have enough points.
        rewardCell = (RewardCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RewardCellOff" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    //number of points you need to use a given reward need to be set
    rewardCell.numberOfPointsRequired.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ pts",reward.pointsRequired];
    //the description needs to be set on the cell
    rewardCell.rewardDescription.text=reward.rewardDescription;
    //the cell needs to be assigned to our rewardCell that we instantiated and dequeued at the beginning on the if
    return rewardCell;
}
return cell;
}
```

EDIT: 
Sorry, in my frustration, I misread some things. It works on one of the the phones with 7.1.2 and another phone with 7.1.2 it does not. I am going to look at the differences.

EDIT 2: 
I found the problem and it was in a piece of code I didn't include:

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
        return 436;
    return 55;
}
```

Comment: The latest version of iOS is currently 7.1.2. There is no such thing as 7.1.13 or 7.1.12. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I am looking into what the differences is between these two phones. They both have 7.1.2. Question edited.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated the question for ya, dunno if it helps

Comment: When things fail on an iPhone 5S but work elsewhere the first thing I would check is for issues due to 64-bit support.

Comment: You could get rid of your else and your nil cell. I would bet that your else is not getting hit and for some reason you never need more that one row. You could log the current row before you if statement as well. Have you added a breakpoint and debugged on the device?

Comment: Yes, the subsequent cells are being created.

Comment: @rmaddy I removed a c-library and the imports to it to see if that was causing the issue, and it was to no avail. The problem still persists.

Comment: Turns out, I am an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here lay in the method I declared having an improper return type that conflicted with 64 bit architectures:

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This returns a float. Everything seems honkey dorey, but in 64 bit architectures this fails because the return type is actually CGFloat which is a macro that can either return double or float. Thus, in non 64 bit architectures, the conversion from float to CGFloat is fine because in 32 bit architectures CGFloat is a float. In 64 bit architectures, CGFloat is a double; however.

Changing this bit fixes the mystery bugs that appeared before.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```